# Can you get the distance from another object with nodes?

Tags: node-editor

It's easy to get the distance from the ***origin*** of an external object by using the "Object" option in the Texture coordinate (through a Vector Math node set to Length).

But what if I want the distance from the ***surface*** of another object (so specifically from the closest point on the surface of another object)?

For example, I could use this value to generate complex volumetric shapes by modeling a very simple mesh and doing the rest with nodes (which is what I want to do).

I could do with either the distance itself or the vector coordinates of the closest point on the surface of an external mesh, either would be appreciated.

I apologize if there's an obvious solution or there's another question answering this on the site, but I was unable to find a solution on the web.

Comment: I'd say no, its not possible. A shader node tree linked to one mesh does not see the surface of another mesh. You can use other tools for that such as Animation Nodes that can make the surface proximity calculations and reflect it to the shader nodes.

Comment: You can do it mathematically if the other object is a very simple shape (cube, sphere, etc.) and you would have to do it manually for every object, but no, the shader itself can't trivially access information about the other objects in the scene

Comment: This may help out.
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/247657/is-it-possible-to-calculate-the-distance-between-the-vertices-of-two-objects-in